# Opening an interactive Jupyter Notebook at breakpoint in VS Code while debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-debugging

I got a fabulous idea where I'd like to be able to open a Jupyter notebook and to use as kernel an active debugging session in VS Code.

Why would you ask? Well, I'd like to add my code interactively. Like coding while debugging. This way I'd code way faster.

Any idea how to do this? This doesn't seem like it's been done and it'd improve my productivity.

Note that I'm using standard debugging sessions without any notebooks involved yet. Suppose that I place my breakpoint in a huge codebase and that I'd like to use this context in a notebook to write the new code and test a few things. I'm not asking about debugging a notebook itself.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a great idea. I am personally looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would save the session and then load it into a new notebook that imports everything from the script you are debugging. You can use the dill package for saving session variables.

```
import dill                            #pip install dill --user
filename = 'globalsave.pkl'
dill.dump_session(filename)

# and to load the session again:
dill.load_session(filename)
```